# How to prove symmetry of a Uniform kernel?

Tags: nonparametric, density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

I am trying to prove this kernel is valid,
$$
K(x) = \frac{1}{2}I(-1 < x < 1)
$$
So far I can integrate to 1, but how do I prove $$k(x) = k(-x)$$
Also, how do we satisfy that k(x) is $\ge$ 0 for all x?

Comment: Since the function is constant for all valid values it should be pretty straightforward, isn’t it?

Comment: The term "kernel" is used for many different entities. Can you please state what you are referring to by "kernel"?

Comment: Proof exercises are frustrating because one's temptation is to declare the theorem "obvious." In fact, they are exercises in a disciplined reading of definitions, axioms and other previously proven theorems. Take the definition of a kernel *verbatim.* Then show through simple mathematical relations that those definitions are true for this kernel. If you feel silly while you are doing it, you are doing it right!

Comment: statistical definition of kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics). So from further study I gathered k(x) = k(-x) means that when you graph the function on a (x,y) plane it is symmetrical. Like how when you graph a normal distribution it is symmetrical. Now I have to see how k(x) is greater than or equal to 0 for all x.

Comment: For the reason we ask for *your* meaning of "kernel," see the "Mathematics" section of the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel).  However, the two questions you ask are so trivial that we have to suspect there might be an issue just understanding the notation.  Could you tell us how you define the function "$I$"?

Comment: whuber, I looked at the the kernel function as a pdf (since all pdfs can be used as kernels) and viewed I as its domain